# Issue while opening Marker in an editor programatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to open a marker, while double-clicking on an entry from a `TableViewer`, inside an eclipse plug-in. I am able to get the associated resource from the marker, however nothing is happening while the `openEditor` method is executed.

The code is as below:

```
  viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
      public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
            try {
                IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
                ReviewIssue reviewIssue = (ReviewIssue) sel.getFirstElement();
                if(reviewIssue != null){
                    MessageDialog.openError(window.getShell(), "Insta Review", reviewIssue.getMarker().getResource());
                    try {
                        IDE.openEditor(window.getActivePage(), reviewIssue.getMarker(), true);
                    } catch (PartInitException e) {
                        MessageDialog.openError(window.getShell(), "Insta Review", e.getMessage());
                    }
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                MessageDialog.openError(window.getShell(), "Insta Review", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
  });
```

Please let me know, if am missing something here. Thanks in advance.
Also ignore the message dialogs, as I plan to implement the logging functionality later.

---

**UPDATE:**

Even though I created the marker on `IFile`, I was getting the same behaviour. I was finally able to open the editor by using the `IFile`, instead of the marker.

```
IFile iFile = markerProject.getFile(path);
//IMarker marker = iFile.createMarker("id.myMarker");
.....
IDE.openEditor(window.getActivePage(), reviewIssue.getiFile(), true);
//IDE.openEditor(window.getActivePage(), reviewIssue.getMarker()), true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work the `IMarker.getResource()` method must return an `IFile`. The code in `IDE.openEditor` is:

```
// get the marker resource file
if (!(marker.getResource() instanceof IFile)) {
    IDEWorkbenchPlugin
                .log("Open editor on marker failed; marker resource not an IFile"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    return null;
}
```

so look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if you are getting that log message.

Normally you would create a marker for a file using the `IFile.createMarker` method (`createMarker` is actually an `IResource` method).

Comment: Its not returning an iFile. What is the criteria for a marker to be associated with an iFile?

Comment: You create the marker using `IFile.createMarker` - normally you don't implement `IMarker` with your own class.

Comment: IResource is OK as long as the resource is a file (not a folder or project)

Comment: I directly used the `iFile` instead of the marker and it started working.